# SqlDataSource delete statement does not work

Tags: vb.net, sqldatasource

can anyone help me with my code, it hits an error in the last line of the code snippet with the error : Additional information: Deleting is not supported by data source '' unless DeleteCommand is specified.

```
Dim ds As New SqlDataSource(sConnectionString, "DELETE FROM dbo.NUVIDA_LT_ASSESSMENTS WHERE ASSESSMENTS_ID = @ASSESSMENTS_ID")
ds.DeleteParameters.Add("ASSESSMENT_ID", ASSESSMENT_ID)

Dim x As Integer = ds.Delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing your delete statement to SqlDataSource object's SELECT statement. So it throws delete command doesn't supported.

Why don't you use just SqlCommand and ExecuteNonQuery method ?

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
    Dim myDelCommand As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.NUVIDA_LT_ASSESSMENTS WHERE ASSESSMENTS_ID = @ASSESSMENTS_ID", connection)
    myDelCommand.Parameters.Add("@ASSESSMENTS_ID", SqlDbType.Int)
    myDelCommand.Parameters("@ASSESSMENTS_ID").Value = 123
    myDelCommand.Connection.Open()
    myDelCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: ok cool, im not to sure how to do it like that? still very new to vb programming

Comment: @AndreaVisnenzaAndy, I added an example.